# What should the "<url>" value be at "git remote add <shortname> <url>"?

Tags: git

I was reading the information at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote, and the syntax to add "a remote named <name> for the repository at <url>" is:

```
git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--[no-]tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>
```

I am trying to understand the value I need to use for `<url>`. What do I need to do on my server? Assuming that in my remote server, I want to place the code at:

```
/home/myusername/public_html/mysourcecode
```

From what I understand, in this case at `/home/myusername/public_html/mysourcecode`, I should have a "public.git" folder, and in that folder, I should have files such as:

[image]

My two questions are:

1) What do I need to do from the server in order to generate the `/home/myusername/public_html/mysourcecode/public.git/` with the content such as it is shown in the image above? Is it just putting my source code at `/home/myusername/public_html/mysourcecode/` and then using `git init`?

2) Once I have `/home/myusername/public_html/mysourcecode/public.git/` with the corresponding content, what would be my `<url>` that I can use in the code below when I add my remote repository?

```
    git remote add [-t <branch>] [-m <master>] [-f] [--[no-]tags] [--mirror=<fetch|push>] <name> <url>
```

I was thinking about using something such as:

```
git remote add mysourcecode ssh://username@domain.com/~myusername/public_html/mysourcecode/public.git
```

However, in that case my value for `<url>` would be `ssh://username@domain.com/~myusername/public_html/mysourcecode/public.git`, and I typically see something such as:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/folder/something.git
```

I would like to know what is the value for `<url>` that I am supposed to use.

Important: I am not using GitHub at all. I have my own server and I only use Git, not GitHub, so I am hosting everything on my own server. Typically I find online help that is specific to GitHub and it does not assume that I am hosting code on my own remote server.

Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to understand the value I need to use for <url>.

Comment: I would like to know what is the value for that <url> I am supposed to use.

Comment: There is no need to speam-repeat your question as a comment multiple times. Wait until an answer is posted. Furthermore, have you *tried* this out? Do you get any error or do you ask "just in case"? from what i can see, the URL you are using seems about right, c.f. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server

Comment: but is **ssh://** required? I would think that saying (without prepending protocol) user@host/path-to-repo should be enough.

Comment: I was repeating parts of my question because <url> was being removed from my test in the question, and I do not know why.

Comment: Yes Polygnome, I had tried what I was asking and not asking "just in case". But understanding what a "bare repository" is was the solution, based on your answer and explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @Edmundo I do not know whether or not "ssh://" is required, but I use it and it works.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya If you have tried something, you should include all relevant error messages, or the expected and observed behavior. I see neither in your post ;)

Comment: Good point Polygnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the Pro Git book, under "Chapter 4: Git on the Server", online available at "https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server".

In order to use a remote repository , this repository must first exist. That means you need to have Git installed on the server.

Next, the repository on the server does not need to have a working directory, it only needs the git metadata. Such a repository is called a *bare* repository.
You can create a bare repository from your old repository *locally* by using

```
$ git clone --bare mysourcecode mysourcecode.git
Cloning into bare repository 'mysourcecode.git'...
done.
```

You want to use Git over SSH as it would seem, so use SSH to copy this *bare* repository to the server, where it will be served by Git later:

```
$ scp -r mysourcecode.git username@domain.com:/~myusername/git
```

I advise against using your `public_html` directory.

Now you can clone this project *locally* by using

```
$ git clone username@domain.com:/~myusername/git/my_project.git
```

Or you add it as remote to the existing repository with

```
$ git remote add origin username@domain.com:/~myusername/git/my_project.git
```

Note that you can skip the `ssh://` and use a colon (`:`) between domain and path. Furthermore, the directory needs to be readable for the SSH user.

---

With regards to the URL with `https://`, this is an alternate way. You can use Git with different protocols - SSH, HTTPS and the Git protocol. All have their strengths and weaknesses.

The above mentioned book covers this topic extensively in Chapter 4, look there for more details, especially for the pros and cons of each protocol.

Comment: This part of your answer is the core part that I needed to learn/understand: "Next, the repository on the server does not need to have a working directory, it only needs the git metadata. Such a repository is called a bare repository." Thank you so much.